# VERP info not added to mail headers?

Tags: civimail

I'm trying to set up the CiviMail return channel, and expect that, if I do it properly, headers like Reply-To and/or Return-Path will have values like bounces+`verp-stuff`@mydomain.com, but so far, that's not happening.

What I've done so far:

1. Created an email account bounces@mydomain.com through Google Apps, and verified it receives an email sent to bounces+123@mydomain.com
2. Edited the default mail account at /civicrm/admin/mailSettings?reset=1, with values (server, username, password, protocol, use ssl) that allow it to check email over IMAP on the bounces@mydomain.com and verified that some messages in that account get labeled with the inbox-civimail-ignored.
3. Also at /civicrm/admin/mailSettings?reset=1, set "Email Domain" = "mydomain.com" and "Used For?" = "Bounce processing".  Other fields in this form are blank.
4. Outbound Email (/civicrm/admin/setting/smtp?reset=1) is set to "mail()"

I then create a new scheduled mailing and send it out using the "Send Scheduled Mailings" job, and the mail arrives with these headers:

```
Delivered-To: me@example.com
Received: by a.a.a.a with SMTP id x3csp113516itf;
        Wed, 29 Jul 2015 10:06:44 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by b.b.b.b with SMTP id o40mr63319942qga.0.1438189604113;
        Wed, 29 Jul 2015 10:06:44 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <b.94.15.1ff1d88a496eafde@mydomain.com>
Received: from mydomain.com (mydomain.com. [c.c.c.c])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id g9si32260106qgf.41.2015.07.29.10.06.43
        for <me@example.com>;
        Wed, 29 Jul 2015 10:06:44 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of b.94.15.1ff1d88a496eafde@mydomain.com designates c.c.c.c as permitted sender) client-ip=c.c.c.c;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of b.94.15.1ff1d88a496eafde@mydomain.com designates c.c.c.c as permitted sender) smtp.mail=b.94.15.1ff1d88a496eafde@mydomain.com
Received: by mydomain.com (Postfix, from userid 33)
    id D96011442D; Wed, 29 Jul 2015 17:06:43 +0000 (UTC)
To: Two Mice <me@example.com>
Subject: test 6fd
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1001:mail.php
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="=_10b250b1b5a6af786cd9e0315548c9d9"
Reply-To: "My Site"
 <info@mydomain.com>
From: "My Site" <info@mydomain.com>
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:u.94.15.1ff1d88a496eafde@mydomain.com>
job_id: 94
Precedence: bulk
X-CiviMail-Bounce: b.94.15.1ff1d88a496eafde@mydomain.com
Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 12:06:43 -0500
Message-Id: <20150729170643.D96011442D@mydomain.com>

--=_10b250b1b5a6af786cd9e0315548c9d9
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Suspecting that our postfix setup might be messing with the headers, I set Outbound Email (/civicrm/admin/setting/smtp?reset=1) to "Redirect to Database", then created a new scheduled mailing and sent it out.  The mail was stored in the civicrm_mailing_spool table with these headers:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="=_6f3fb5f7026a6aecc8d6a73af912a390"
Reply-To: "My Site"
 <info@mydomain.com>
Return-Path: b.100.16.af889b4c23dd0331@mydomain.com
From: "My Site" <info@mydomain.com>
Subject: test 7
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:u.100.16.af889b4c23dd0331@mydomain.com>
job_id: 100
To: Two Mice <me@example.com>
Precedence: bulk
X-CiviMail-Bounce: b.100.16.af889b4c23dd0331@mydomain.com | --=_6f3fb5f7026a6aecc8d6a73af912a390
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

**Question:** What else should I do to get bounces to be directed to my bounces@mydomain.com address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Mail Accounts entry you set up, you need to set `bounces+` as the localpart.  Everything else looks good.

In your examples, you have b.94.15.1ff1d88a496eafde@mydomain.com as the return-path in the the first one and b.100.16.af889b4c23dd0331@mydomain.com in the second.  CiviMail just needs to know to tack "bounces+" on the front of those addresses, and that's where the localpart comes in.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. With your answer in hand, I googled 'civicrm mail account local part' and found this documentation: http://book.civicrm.org/user/version/4.1/initial-set-up/email-system-configuration  That setting does the trick!